# How to find the name of the database currently used?

Tags: sql-server, database

I am working on Microsoft SQL server management studio. I have 15 different databases under the Databases folder. All the databases have similar structure and tables. I wrote a query that will work on any database. However i want to know how can I find out the name of the currently used database, I want this to show in my result set. Please advise?

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you need the [`DB_NAME()`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189753.aspx) function.

It accepts an optional `database_id` parameter. If omitted it returns the name of the current database.

Answer (score 0):

DB_NAME() method can get you the name of the current database.
Answered by StuartLC.